# bash loop writing over next file

Tags: bash

I am trying to process multiple `bam` files in a loop using the standard and having an issue where each file overwrites the other. The `--bam xxx \` is the only line that will change and the `xxx` depends on the `bam` files in the directory. In this example there are three, but that is not always the case. Thank you :).

**files in directory**   --- won't always be three ---

```
xxx_00.bam
yyy_01.bam
zzz_02.bam
```

**standard**

```
for bam in *.bam ; do
 ${path_to_strelka}/bin/configureStrelkaGermlineWorkflow.py \
   --bam ${bam} \
   --referenceFasta $fasta \
   --callRegions $bed \
   --exome
   --runDir $dir
 $dir/runWorkflow.py -m local -j 20
done
```

**desired**

```
for bam in *.bam ; do
 ${path_to_strelka}/bin/configureStrelkaGermlineWorkflow.py \
   --bam ${bam} \   --- xxx_00.bam ---
   --bam ${bam} \   --- yyy_01.bam ---
   --bam ${bam} \   --- zzz_02.bam ---
   --referenceFasta $fasta \
   --calRegions $bed \
   --exome \
   --runDir $dir
 $dir/runWorkflow.py -m local -j 20
done
```

**Tried** --- prints the desired but does not execute it ---

```
printf -- "${path_to_strelka}/bin/configureStrelkaGermlineWorkflow.py \\\\\n%s\n\t\t--referenceFasta $fasta \\\\\n\t\t--callRegions $bed \\\\\n\t\t--exome \\\\\n\t\t--runDir ${dir}\n" \
"$(for f in *.bam; do printf -- "\t\t--bam %s \\\\\n"    "${f}"; done)"
${dir}/runWorkflow.py -m local -j 20
```

Comment: Your question wording confuses me - not sure what bam files are either. Checking the existence of a file might help? A scenario of what is happening vs what is desired would clarify - with sample file names in folders..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look to me like you need the loop at all.

```
${path_to_strelka}/bin/configureStrelkaGermlineWorkflow.py \
    $( printf " --bam %s " *bam ) \
   --referenceFasta $fasta \
   --calRegions $bed \
   --exome \
   --runDir $dir \
$dir/runWorkflow.py -m local -j 20
```

Comment: You could also have just wrapped `$( )`'s around your `printf`.

Comment: Thank you very much I have been trying to figure that out for a bit :).